#  batch file - specify order that sql files are executed in

Tags: batch-file

I have a bat file which executes a list of sql files. I usually place them in order, but on some machines the order is changed e.g. default is to order by date modified etc. Is it possible to get this bat file to run the scripts in the following order: first run items with a 1. prefix then 2. then 3. and so forth?

```
@echo on
set server=.\Dev05
set catalog=MyDb
set user=sa
set password=myPassword

echo ----------------ERROR LOG---------------- > ErrorLog.txt
echo . >> ErrorLog.txt

FOR %%f IN (*.sql) DO (
echo --------%%f Output-------- >> ErrorLog.txt 
SQLCMD -S%server% -d%catalog% -U%user% -P%password% -I -i "%%f" >> ErrorLog.txt
echo . >> ErrorLog.txt 
)

pause
```

Comment: I would recommend moving away from BAT files and on to powershell scripts if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have thought the `FOR` should already be working, but if you want to force an order, I think this should work:

```
FOR /F %%f IN ('dir /B /O:N *.sql') DO (
```

Where you're asking the `dir` command to sort the file names in name order.

Comment: That will work if you have 9 or fewer files, otherwise the order would be 1.*, 10.* 11.*...19.*2.*,20.*...

Comment: @PatrickCuff - true, but I can't think of a simple solution if you do number above 9 - any ideas? (and the OP indicated they had multiple files starting with 1, 2 and 3, with no indicated preference for execution order within each group)

Comment: @PatrickCuff - If more than 9 files, then either move on to letters, or else 0 prefix the number as needed.

Comment: @dbenham - doh! obvious really - Just make sure that the files sort correctly on names, whatever scheme is being used

Comment: @dbenham; I don't know if the OP has control over naming these files, or if they even want to. The solution in my answer will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
@echo OFF

:: Count number of SQL files to set upper limit on outer loop:
@for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /A-d /b *.sql') do @set /a count+=1 > NUL

for /l %%i in (1,1,%count%) do (
    if exist %%i.*.sql (
        for %%f in ( %%i.*.sql) do (
            @echo Process file %%f
            . . .
        )
    ) else (
        exit /b
    )
)
```

Remove the `else ( exit /b )` statement if you have gaps in your sequence.